# How would you simplify this ruby method that splits an array based on its content?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I want to do this

```
apples, bananas = sort_basket
```

So I made this method

```
def sort_basket
  apples = []
  bananas = []
  basket.each do |fruit|
    if fruit.apple?
      apples << apple
    else
      bananas << banana
    end
  end
  [apples, bananas]
end
```

But I can't help but feel there must be a more elegant and/or more concise way of achieving the same behavior for `sort_basket`.

How would you do it ?

Comment: Relevant question, but it's an example I made up and I thought it was not really important. It would probably be an array of Apple and Banana objects ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to separate an array:

```
apples, bananas = basket.partition(&:apple?)
```

Comment: oops, beaten by 15 seconds :)

Comment: Aaah, that's what I'm talking about :)
Thanks !